# Hyperlink is not accepting space in android

Tags: android, html, xml, hyperlink

It may look simple but i am quite stuck in this problem ,I want to add a hyper link in my application Eg: www.example of an address with spaces.html

but when i put the url in code it looks like this 
[image]

here's my code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:linksClickable="true"

        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="http://www.example of an address with spaces.html" />
```

Comment: Don't use spaces in URLs. They don't belong there. But: use %20 (instead of space) in the String, then it should work.

Comment: I know that but is there any other alternative to do it

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
tvTermsOfUse.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tv_terms_of_use_html)));
    Linkify.addLinks(tvTermsOfUse, Linkify.ALL);
    tvTermsOfUse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_terms_of_use"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />


<string name="tv_terms_of_use_html"><![CDATA[This is link to <a href="http://google.com/">Google with spaces</a>.]]></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this `programmatically` its *simple and easy*

Remove `android:text="http://www.example of an address with spaces.html"` this from your `xml code`

Add Following to your `java code`

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=www.google.com>link with space</a>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the folowing,

```
TextView mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view_html);
String text =
"Visit <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">Google home page</a>";
mTextView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
mTextView1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try XML CDATA

```
 <string name="demoStr"><Data><![CDATA[ <b>ABC</b> ]]> </Data></string>
```